# Dealing with not quite unique data?

Tags: database, pandas

What do people do if there is non-unique data on files which can and should be joined?

My example is for customer data. One file would track the start of an interaction and how long it took from a system perspective. The other file would keep track of the interaction when the employee logs it - this is typically done at the end of the interaction but there can be delays. So there is no way to match up the timestamps between File 1 and File 2. I would want to determine the Duration and Rating for specific Issue types across 3 files.

I typically create an index (in pandas) which is `Date | CustomerID | EmployeeID` which works decently most of the time (that customer interacted with that employee on that date). But sometimes the same customer interacts with the same customer on the same day so I have a duplicate value. This didn't bother me before until I notice my joins (pd.merge) caused duplicate data and, by chance, an outlier interaction was duplicated which threw off some analysis.

Should I completely drop any interaction with duplicates? Should I create a more unique ID based on some type of time interval (like if the EndDatetime is within X minutes from the Datetime on another file (which is close to the end of the interaction normally)?

File 1:

```
StartDatetime | CustomerID | EmployeeID | Duration | EndDatetime
```

File 2:

```
Datetime | CustomerID | EmployeeID | Issue
```

File 3:

```
Datetime | CustomerID | EmployeeID | Rating
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct answer to this question relies more on the use cases for your data than anything else. Personally I deal with interaction data a lot, in those cases I prefer indexing by interaction time as well, since the two interactions are truly unique. However, if the analysis I'm performing doesn't take into account the amount of interactions taking place, and just the parties involved, dropping duplicate interactions is preferred. In other cases, grouping is preferable, but since each interaction in your example appears to be truly independent, grouping seems ill-advised, the only criteria you could naturally group on would be rating, and seems like a bad decision to aggregate that separately from any analytics you're performing.

Comment: Yeah, I use the time as well if is applicable. The issue for me is that I am measuring calls when they reach an agent (Start Time) and then the 'case log' which when the agent closes the account and leaves notes. This is sometime after the start of the call.. and then the agent might get another call and not notate the first call for sometime later. Perhaps I could round the timestamp to the nearest 30 minutes or 1 hour?

Comment: This is a common problem for me as well. The way I'm currently dealing with it involves a lot of range calculations, if there's an "acceptable" time frame for an agent to close their tickets, events within that time frame that have the same customer and employer id should be treated the same

Comment: I think that is fair enough and worth testing (total samples if I just drop duplicates on a daily basis versus a 'acceptable time frame' window. What kind of code could I create to do that? Like I take the timestamp of the 'ticket' file and then the actual timestamp of a call. How could I try to match the tickets to a timestamp within 30 minutes or something like that?

Comment: Pandas has robust time series tools, the exact answer will depend on the implementation of your dataframes, but you can parse datetimes and do whatever math you like on them (subtract one from another) and then chck that they're smaller than some pd.timedelta